# how do i shift my movmean function by y=mx+c to adjust for data creep

Tags: matlab-figure

[image: See the top graph]

This is the code:

```
subplot(3,1,1);
plot(Fz(500:1200000),'Color','k');
hold on
M1 = movmean(Fz(500:1200000),[2000,2000]);
plot(M1,'Color','r')
```

Any ideas on how to shift my `movmean` function by `y=mx+c` to adjust for data creep?

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is called [`detrend`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/detrend.html). Either way, you don't shift the `movmean`, rather, you shift the _data_ and apply `movmean` on the result.